# KeyboardAvoidingView has a little overlay on the input?

Tags: react-native

I struggle to set the input field right above the keyboard in android platform it's working but not as I like. I need to set the input completely right after the keyboard. I tried some similar questions solution but no luck. here's my code:

```js
return (
<KeyboardAvoidingView behavior={undefined} style={styles.screen}>
        <View style={styles.chatRequestContainer}>
          <TextInput
            multiline
            style={styles.textInput}
            placeholderTextColor={colors.secondary}
            placeholder="Write your request"
          />
          <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.8} style={styles.sendBtn}>
            <Send width={25} height={25} stroke={'#fff'} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
)

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#0B0D15',
  },
  chatRequestContainer: {
    // paddingVertical: 10,
    height: 80,
    // maxHeight: 140,
    borderTopWidth: 1,
    borderBlockColor: '#222841',
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    bottom: 0,
    position: 'absolute',
    width: '100%',
  },
  textInput: {
    backgroundColor: '#161A2A',
    borderRadius: 30,
    paddingHorizontal: 15,
    flex: 1,
  },
  sendBtn: {
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#222841',
    width: 55,
    height: 55,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderRadius: 35,
    // marginLeft: 10,
  },
});
```

here is the image of the result which is the issue:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the weirdness is happening because of the TextInput parent container is absolutely positioned. To get the view to stick to the bottom of the screen you can just wrap it in another container and give it use flex and justifyContent to get it to stick to the bottom:

```js
import {
  Text,
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
  TextInput,
} from 'react-native';
import { Feather } from '@expo/vector-icons';

const colors = {
  secondary: '#dca396',
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.screen}>
      <View style={styles.footer}>
        <View style={styles.chatRequestContainer}>
          <TextInput
            multiline
            style={styles.textInput}
            placeholderTextColor={colors.secondary}
            placeholder="Write your request"
          />
          <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.8} style={styles.sendBtn}>
            <Feather
              name="send"
              size={25}
              color="white"
              style={styles.centerImage}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#0B0D15',
  },
  chatRequestContainer: {
   // paddingVertical: 10,
    height: 80,
    // maxHeight: 140,
    borderTopWidth: 1,
    borderBlockColor: '#222841',
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    bottom: 0,
    // position: 'absolute',
    width: '100%',
  },
  textInput: {
    backgroundColor: '#161A2A',
    borderRadius: 30,
    paddingHorizontal: 15,
    flex: 1,
    height:'60%'
  },
   sendBtn: {
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#222841',
    width: 55,
    height: 55,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderRadius: 35,
    // marginLeft: 10,
  },
  footer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  },
  centerImage: {
    alingSelf: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

[demo](https://snack.expo.dev/A0JrBwoWq)

Comment: I found that once you wrap the component in the footer view that  you can do absolute positioning with no problems. So maybe its just that `KeyboardAvoidingView` direct descendants behave unexpectedly when they are absolutely positioned

Comment: Thanks for your response @phantomSpooks. I did as you said and also I checked the demo you provided. everything seems right inside the demo but still in my Android phone which is OPPO CPH2325 the issue is not solved and I don't know why. you have any alternative? IDK if it is only in this kind of phone no problem but I'm worried about other phones and unfortunately I can't test on other phones or emulators right now.

Comment: Also I tried on some Emulators with Genymotion, the issue is the same. I'm really confused...

Comment: I haven't used a KeyboardAvoidingView in quite some time, but I had a distant memory of a third party package being better than the react native one. I did a quick search but couldnt find it (maybe I was thinking of SafeAreaView?).

Comment: Maybe you can use the [useKeyboard](https://github.com/react-native-community/hooks#usekeyboard) hook to get the keyboard height and then manually re-position the view?

Comment: Im trying to get a useKeyboard hook example working and I see what you mean. Even without using a KeyboardAvoiding View on expo snack the content is automagically moving when the keyboard appears

Answer (score 0):

I think that react native's default behavior is to try to automatically handle doing the keyboard avoiding view stuff for you. I think that you can turn this off (in expo you edit [softwareKeyboardLayout](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/config/app/#softwarekeyboardlayoutmode) in  your app.json; and im not sure how to do it in react native (in android you can edit a the manifest.xml to get this result but Im not sure about iOS).

I think that the weirdness you are encountering is probably because of how different phone manufacturers handle the softwareKeyboardLayout. To get all apps to behave the same I'd recommend changing the softwareKeyboardLayout and then manually reacting to the keyboard coming/going:

```js
import {
  Text,
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
  TextInput,
  Keyboard,
} from 'react-native';
import { Feather } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { useKeyboard } from '@react-native-community/hooks';
import Animated, {
  useSharedValue,
  useAnimatedStyle,
  useAnimatedReaction,
  withTiming,
} from 'react-native-reanimated';
const colors = {
  secondary: '#dca396',
};

export default function App() {
  // use hook to get keyboard details
  const keyboard = useKeyboard();
  // keyboard height animated value
  const keyboardHeight = useSharedValue(0);
  const animatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      top: keyboardHeight.value || undefined,
    };
  });
  // react to keyboard state changes
  useAnimatedReaction(
    () => {
      return {
        keyboardShown:keyboard.keyboardShown,
        keyboardHeight:keyboard.keyboardHeight
      }
    },
    (prev, curr) => {
      if(!prev || !curr) return
      keyboardHeight.value = withTiming(
        curr.keyboardShown ? curr.keyboardHeight : 0
      );
    }
  );
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.screen}>
      <Animated.View style={[styles.chatRequestContainer, animatedStyle]}>
        <TextInput
          multiline
          style={styles.textInput}
          placeholderTextColor={colors.secondary}
          placeholder="Write your request"
        />
        <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.8} style={styles.sendBtn}>
          <Feather
            name="send"
            size={25}
            color="white"
            style={styles.centerImage}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </Animated.View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#0B0D15',
    padding: 10,
  },
  chatRequestContainer: {
    // paddingVertical: 10,
    height: 80,
    // maxHeight: 140,
    borderTopWidth: 1,
    borderBlockColor: '#222841',
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    // top:0,
    bottom: 0,
    position: 'absolute',
    width: '100%',
  },
  textInput: {
    backgroundColor: '#161A2A',
    borderRadius: 30,
    paddingHorizontal: 15,
    flex: 1,
  },
  sendBtn: {
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#222841',
    width: 55,
    height: 55,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderRadius: 35,
    // marginLeft: 10,
  },
  centerImage: {
    alingSelf: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

[demo](https://snack.expo.dev/lGsGHd_94)

Comment: You may not need to edit softwareKeyboardLayout with the code above but Im not sure since I have only tested on Expo Snack's android device and the emulator from Android Studio